# How to find a word within an href link in a div element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, switch-statement

There is a div element that always contain one of the array words inside an a href element. Depending on what the word is, I need the web page to redirect to a different page. I'm not sure what I a missing.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Legahgn/5/

```
 if ($('.container-fluid:contains("It looks something like this")').length > 0 || ($('.container-fluid:contains("Have you visited")').length > 0)) {
var uTest = ["Saggitarius", "Quentin", "Cinthia", "Maleria", "Pete", "Library", "wizard"];
var aTest = uTest.length;
var i = 0;
for (i; i < aTest; i++) {
    if ($('.container-fluid:contains("'+uTest[i]+'")').length > 0) {
        var mTest = uTest[i];
        if (mTest != null || undefined) {
            switch (mTest) {
                case "Saggitarius":
                    window.location.href = 'https://subeta.net/quests.php/saggitarius';
                    break;
                case "Quentin":
                    window.location.href = '...';
                    break;
                case "Cinthia":
                    window.location.href = '...';
                    break;
              case "Maleria":
                    window.location.href = '...';
                    break;
                case "Pete":
                    alert("Pete");
                    break;
              case "Library":
                    window.location.href = '...';
                    break;
              case "wizard":
                    window.location.href = '...';
                    break;
                case "Mori":
                    window.location.href = '...';
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            alert("done");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is a really bad way to choose links. For instance you are now dependent on the misspelling of `Sagittarius` (it has one `g` - I happen to be a Sagittarius). Better off putting the links into the page (as data- attributes?). :)

Comment: There is a parse error here `$(.container-fluid:contains(uTest[i]))`. This should be `$('.container-fluid:contains("'+uTest[i]+'")')`

Comment: Thanks, solved the error with your fix + var i = 0. I'm running this on tampermonkey, that's why Saggitarius is the actual link to the webpage and it never changes.